# AWS DMS - How to select different databases for source and target points for a task

Tags: mysql-5.7, aws, amazon-dms

Does aws DMS(Data Migration service) allow to select different databases  for source and target points for a task in a replication instance? My source engine is MySQL. 
example: I want to move table A from database D1 to D2. but i am not able to do in DMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the Solution! yes it(AWS DMS) allows to move tables from database D1 to D2. just need to configure transformation rule section properly in JSON section. Plese refer below link within section "Example Rename a Schema"

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.html